Modelling hoist with wire rope in OpenModelica
Is there a way to model pulleys and cables similar to the solutions incorporated in Maplesoft and Simscape in OpenModelica?
I'm just starting out and I'm playing around with simulating a hoist's dynamic response so I'm wanting to model the drum/pulley and rope components.

Maybe you could have a look into the Modelica.Mechanics.MultiBody library. But that will probably require some modification.
